# How can I deconstruct a variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, typeof

I am trying to practise a question on hackerrank.
[Problem link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/new-year-chaos/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=arrays)

I am trying to read the variable q

```js
function minimumBribes(q) {
  // Write your code here
  console.log(typeof(q))

}
/* outputs-    
    Object
    Object
*/
function minimumBribes(q) {
  // Write your code here
  console.log(q)

}
/* outputs-    
    [2,3,4,5,1]
    [3,5,4,2,1]
*/
function minimumBribes(q) {
  // Write your code here
  console.log(q[0])

}
/* outputs-    
    2
    3
*/
```

How do I get the two arrays stored in two different variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carefully consider the way the solution template is written, the function minimimumBribes is being called with two different test cases one after another, not as array of test cases. You would want to do some processing and print the solution for each case in new line.

As for deconstruction of arrays in javascript:

```
let a, b, together = [10, 20];
[a, b] = together;

console.log(a);
// expected output: 10

console.log(b);
// expected output: 20
```